# Adding Text / Caption to Thumbnail Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caption

I need to add a caption to each image. But the caption needs to be within a grey box next to the slider. You can see an example of the idea here:
http://pagedev.co.uk/richmond/show-open.html

Basically every image needs to have a title, oil on canvas and size tag. But it needs to change with every image.

Hopefully someone can help me. You should be able to check the code using the link above, but if you need anything let me know and ill post it up.

Thank you in advance.

Lee

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this as I don't have all of your images but I think this is what you want :)

```
<div class="col span_9_of_12">
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
<img src="images/large1.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/large2.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/large3.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/large4.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/large5.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/large6.jpg" />
<div class="painting-description">
<p><strong>The Heart of Suffolk</strong></p>
<p>(on a typically rainy day) 1965</p>
<p>Oil on canvas</p>
<p>28 x 34 inches</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the description to be part of the slider you need to store the descriptions somewhere (for example in a javascript array).

Then you can use the `before` option of flexslider (see Step 4 on http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) to replace the content of `.painting-description`